# Fail to build React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

When I tried to run this command:  `react-native run-ios`

The terminal returns this.
How to solve this?

```
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1


** BUILD FAILED **



The following build commands failed:
    CodeSign build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/albums.app
(1 failure)
```

Comment: Do you have any unused third party library under node_modules?